# Django: Chicken or Egg question

Tags: python, django, design-patterns, application-design

I am building an application that will send an API call and save the resulting information after processing the information in a `APIRecord(models.Model)` class.

**1)** Should I build a separate class in such a way that the class does the API call, processes the information (including checking against business rules) and then creates an instance of my `APIRecord()` class?

Or

**2)** Should I build a separate class with the appropriate methods for processing, and calling the API, and then in my model, override the `APIRecord.save()` method to call the separate class's API methods and then save the results?

Or

**3)** Should I build my model class with the appropriate methods for calling the API and processing the response (including checking for certain values and other business rules)?

I tried # 2 and ran into problems with flexibility (but am still open to suggestion). I'm leaning towards # 1, but I'm not sure of all the negatives yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is design decision.
it depends to your design and programming interests.
i used the combination of three methods you said. if i need to some informations that can be build from other fields then i will create an internal function in model class. if i need other records of database to do something i will create an function outside of model class. and other unusual needs will be computed everywhere i need them.